# Redefinition of Functions Error

Tags: c++, mobile

I am making a mobile app with the C++ API Mosync(2.7) the IDE uses eclipse. When I compile I get these errors & I'm not sure how I fix them:

> c:/slave/buildScripts/temp_EjFB/source/libs/libsupc++/new_opvnt.cc:1:
>   Error: Symbol '__Znam' is already defined,
>   c:/slave/buildScripts/temp_EjFB/source/libs/libsupc++/new_opnt.cc:37:
>   Error: Symbol '__Znwm' is already defined,
>   c:/slave/buildScripts/temp_EjFB/source/libs/libsupc++/del_opvnt.cc:68:
>   Error: Symbol '__ZdaPv' is already defined,
>   c:/slave/buildScripts/temp_EjFB/source/libs/libsupc++/del_opnt.cc:36:
>   Error: Symbol '__ZdlPv' is already defined,
>   c:/slave/buildScripts/temp_EjFB/source/libs/MAStd/maxtoa.c:40: Error:
>   Symbol '_xtoa' is already defined,

I'm pretty sure when I created my project I selected NativeUI project(or maybe NativeUI C++). And my build settings are:

Include Paths: %mosync-home%/include
Library Paths: %mosync-home%/lib/pipe
Additional Libs: mastd.lib, MAUtil.lib, NativeUI.lib

There is a copy of my whole project here if it will help: http://www.mosync.com/content/build-error-redefinition-functions

**How can I get my project to compile?**

Comment: It looks like you are trying to link your program against those libraries more than once. Check your linker settings.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have included the same library twice.

You should check this in you project settings.

I will point the MoSync support team at this question, sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to include `mastd.lib` unless "Ignore Default" checkboxes are checked.

I suggest to create a new project from a template (using File/New Project...) and copy the settings in that project. In your project the only field that should need to be filled in is:

```
Additional Libraries: MAUtil.lib, NativeUI.lib
```

You can also post questions to the MoSync Forum: http://www.mosync.com/forum
Hopefully, you will get a quicker response at the forum :)